# UITableViewCell Accessory is too wide on iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

I am having a problem with my UITableViewCell's appearance on the iPad. This problem arose sometime between iOS 7 and now, but I don't know for sure when it started. On an iPod or iPhone my cells look fine (portrait or landscape), but on the iPad, the disclosure accessory is very wide. You can see an example in the image below. The tablecell has a green border and the contentview has a brown border. The content view is much smaller than it should be. Table cells without the disclosure accessory look fine.

[image: Example]

I am using Xamarin, and I am creating this UI completely in code. Here is the code (I have omitted the code that lays out the inside of the cells ContentView since it isn't relevant:

```
protected void Draw()
    {
        Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

        Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Green.CGColor;
        Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;

        Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 320, 42);
        ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
        AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;

        ContentView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
        ContentView.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;
        ContentView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;
        ContentView.ClipsToBounds = true;
        ContentView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Brown.CGColor;
        ContentView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;

    }
```

I tried changing the size of the ContentView by overriding the cell's LayoutSubviews method. However, the ContentView was now as wide as the table, but the disclosure accessory didn't change and was now below the ContentView.

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        //ContentView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, Frame.Size.Width, ContentView.Frame.Size.Height);
    }
```

Again, this isn't a problem at all on the iPhone or iPod. I don't understand what I should be doing different for the iPad to work properly.

Thanks.
Zach Green

**Edit - 10/21/2015 11:00**
For the moment, I have made a very hacky change that is fixing the issue for me, but I know that future iOS updates will probably break this, so I would prefer a more iOS approved way to do this.

```
public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        //!! - Hack for ipad layout issue with disclosure indicator
        if (Accessory == UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator && UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
        {
            ContentView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, Frame.Size.Width - 32, ContentView.Frame.Size.Height);

            foreach (var view in Subviews.OfType<UIButton>())
            {
                view.Frame = new CGRect(Frame.Size.Width - 24, view.Frame.Y, 8, view.Frame.Height);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is you are hardcoding the frame size: `Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 320, 42);` and setting a fixed width. While iPhone has a 320 pixel screen width, iPad has a 768 pixel screen width so, this breaks your UI there

Comment: so, should i just be omitting that line?

Comment: After looking more closely to your code it seems you are not setting the Frame or the ContentMode or the AutoresizingMask properties anywhere.... Why are you initializing them then ?

Comment: I am setting the Frame and AutoresizingMask in the Draw method. I guess what bothers me is that everything looks good the way I have it, except for cells with Accessories.

Comment: The contentView looks to be 600 wide which would imply it is using Any/Any size class which usually means it has no size class. How are you creating the cells? Make sure you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifer:forIndexPath rather than the version which has no indexPath. The former returns a cell with a valid size class while the latter does not.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is due to Apples new readable content margins in iOS9 intended to make content more readable in wider views (iPad Pro).

You can turn this feature off by setting

```
tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```

in viewDidLoad

Comment: "_This layout guide defines an area that can easily be read without forcing users to move their head to track the lines_" ...If I had a dime for every book I threw out because of minor head movement..

Comment: It took 4 hours to finally figure this out. If I want a table or cell to be smaller I can do that in less than 2 seconds. Why on earth these guys think they can just mess with custom designs with a turned On default option!

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
    protected void Draw()
        {
            Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

            Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Green.CGColor;
            Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;

            Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].keywindow.frame.size.width, 42);
            ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
            AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;

            ContentView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
            ContentView.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;
            ContentView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;
            ContentView.ClipsToBounds = true;
            ContentView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.Brown.CGColor;
            ContentView.Layer.BorderWidth = 1f;

        }

public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        //!! - Hack for ipad layout issue with disclosure indicator
        if (Accessory == UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator && UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
        {
            ContentView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].keywindow.frame.size.width - 32, ContentView.Frame.Size.Height);

            foreach (var view in Subviews.OfType<UIButton>())
            {
                view.Frame = new CGRect([UIApplication sharedApplication].keywindow.frame.size.width - 24, view.Frame.Y, 8, view.Frame.Height);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the width same as that of `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame.size.width` rather than hardcoding the values.