# Accessory view seems to occupy more space in landscape view - IOS 9

Tags: tableview, ios9, accessoryview

I recently upgraded all my simulators to IOS9 and found issues with the accessory view.  The accessory view occupies more space in Landscape mode, which looks awkward. Does anybody have an idea abt this

Landscape:
[image]

---

Portrait:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution :

setting cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth property of your tableview to false :

```
tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
```

[more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410884/2773267)